# database index optimization for advice

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

Suppose I have query like (on MySQL),

```
select xxx from table x
where col_a=yyy and col_b=zzz
```

And suppose I have a combination index of col_a and col_b together. My question is how this combination index helps better than using single index on either col_a or col_b? Will combination index boost query performance as I posted? Wondering why? Thanks.

regards,
Lin

Comment: That is **highly dependent** on which actual, concrete database system you're using. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s, thanks, I am talking about MySQL. Will update my original question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes a composite index will help (except if one of the predicates is always extremely selective on its own).

Consider a phone directory.

If it was just ordered by a single key `LastName` with no ordering within those sharing the same surname then looking up "Martin Smith" (`WHERE FirstName='Martin' AND LastName='Smith'`) out of all the other Smith's will take much longer than looking up in a directory ordered by the composite key of `LastName,FirstName`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, interesting example, how database underlying treating the composite index? Index Last name + first name as a single value (just like how they index a single column)?

Comment: @LinMa The rows in the index pages will contain both columns and it will be possible to differentiate them rather than just concatenating them together but binary search can work with two columns. E.g is `(Smith,Martin)` before or after `(Jones,David)`. The upper levels of the B tree will contain details of the first (or last) composite key value for each page in the level below.

Comment: Thanks Martin, another confusion is, what do you mean "extremely selective on its own"? I think it means less duplicate values (e.g. suppose last name is more selective, the same last name could match one or very few records, other than match a lot of records), correct?

Comment: @LinMa Yes. If every surname was only shared by a handful of people you might as well just index that single column and just check the residual predicate on first name against the handful of matches.

Comment: Thanks Martin. In a general case, using two single indexes will first look at what records are matched by last name, then among the matched records, will look at if first name also match. If the process I described here is correct, it sounds to be the same as using composite index -- let us make it simple, saying composite index just concatenating the two column values, I think searching the concatenating string of first name and last name, is almost the same as the two phases search of using two single indexes?

Comment: So, what is the performance boost by using composite index? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. And appreciate if a bit more details about why composite index faster in general case. :)

Comment: @LinMa in the general case two single indexes could either have a plan where only one was used and a residual predicate is used for the other or both could be used and the results joined (index intersection). I dont know if MySQL uses index intersection plans though now you've added that tag.

Comment: Thanks Martin, good reference. What exactly do you mean "residual predicate"?

Comment: @LinMa - The predicate that is left over from the seek and still needs to be evaluated. e.g. if a single column index on `LastName` is used to find "Martin Smith"  then the seek predicate is "Smith" but the residual predicate of `WHERE FirstName='Martin'` still needs to be evaluated against all Smiths.

Answer (score 3):

For the query that you provide, any composite index that starts with `col_a, col_b` or `col_b, col_a` matches the `where` clause (assuming that `yyy` and `zzz` are constants).

Such a composite index can be used to directly find the values with the given rows.  I think MySQL's [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) does a pretty good job of explaining the concepts, which apply to any database.

The best index would include the columns in the `select` list as well.  Such an index "covers" the query, meaning that the index can satisfy the query and accessing the original data pages is unnecessary.

An index is not *always* helpful.  For instance, if all rows had the same values in the two columns, then using an index does not add any benefit -- and could even slow things down a wee bit.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Wondering if composite index does not exists, how the query leveraging single column index col_a and col_b? I am not sure if it works in this way, it uses single column index col_a to find all records whose col_a value are satisfied (equal to 'yyy'), then among the satisfied records, it will further find full satisfied records (whose col_b equal to 'zzz')? If so, my confusion is, in the 2nd step, how SQL engine is able to use index on col_b to find full satisfied value -- since 2nd phase query is based on a subset of records?

Comment: subset of records (means, records whose col_a is satisfied). Does index on col_b help if search on a subset of records?

Comment: An index on either column will work, but not as well as an index on both columns.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, what do you mean "not as well as an index on both columns"? A bit more details are appreciated. :)

Comment: Some indexes are better than other.  An index with both columns will have (in general) better performance than an index with only one column.

Comment: @LinMa -- See [_cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and [_composite indexing_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1).

Comment: @RickJames, good reference, I take time to study => http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1, but confused in section of covering index, specifically the comments -- `The "data" BTree is not touched`. I think index column are stored in a BTree so that value on index column could be searched -- we can call it index BTree. But what means data BTree? Thanks.

Comment: The entire table (except for secondary indexes) is stored on disk in a BTree structure, ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY` (in the case of InnoDB).  "Secondary keys" (other indexes than the `PRIMARY KEY`) are each stored in another BTree.  This BTree contains the columns of the secondary key and of the PK, but not the rest of the table's columns.

Comment: Using your example, plus assuming a PK of `id`, `INDEX(col_a, col_b)` would be a secondary key.  After locating the row(s) in that BTree with `yyy` and `zzz`, a second lookup is needed to find `xxx` by using `id` to find the row in the "data BTree".  `INDEX(col_a, col_b, xxx)` would be a "covering" index for your example -- because `xxx` would be sitting right there in the index.  This is a little faster because it avoids that second lookup.